# crontab mutt email fails to be sent

Tags: cron, mutt

I have a crontab which is supposed to send an email, but it doesn't.

```
echo " ok backup  " > /home/nuvoshift01/zDB-backup-start.txt
mysqldump --opt --user=q --password=xyz --host=localhost giladparking > /home/nuvoshift01/GPmonthly-DBdump.sql
mutt me@gmail.com -s "MySQL BackUp" -a /home/nuvoshift01/GPmonthly-DBdump.sql  < /home/nuvoshift01/zDB-backup-start.txt > /home/nuvoshift01/whatHappened.txt
touch /home/nuvoshift01/zDB-bacup-end.txt
```

(1) the first line does touch the file as coded

(2) the back up file is created

(3) the mutt mail does not send

(4) the 4th line does touch the file as coded

if I issue the mutt command from the command the email IS sent with the attachment

my puzzle/question is: why doesn't the email get sent by the crontab?

Answer (score 2):

OK, today I provide the solution to my own problem. I determined to send the email with mutt I needed to create a properly configured .muttrc file AND explicitly describe the path in the cron task.

my .muttrc file looks like this :

```
set from = "anyaddress@anydomain.com"
set hostname = hostname.com
set envelope_from = yes
```

the mutt command needs to look like this:

```
mutt -F /home/user/.muttrc  -s "SUBJECT"  any@address.com -a /home/user/attachedfile.txt < /home/user/bodyofmessage.txt
```

It turns out the message will likely end up in the spam folder of the recipient.

A special thank you for Major Hayden at Rack Space for his assistance behind the scenes.